# Hero header on "About Us" page overlaps navigation bar menus

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When visiting the [About Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company) page for SO, I noticed the menus display behind the big blue "Learn, Share, Build" banner. See below.

[image]

The same thing happens with each menu item.

> Browser: Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: [z-index strikes again ....](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=z-index+%5Bbug%5D)

Comment: Please don't post link to website, share the code here .... :p

Comment: I find the color blue much more valuable and interesting than the actual text of the help/tour menu box. I'd call this an accidental feature, not a bug. ;)

Comment: So where should I look? I can't find a [free hand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#19775).

Comment: This also happens on Firefox v60.0 (64bit). I suspect the colour is actually "pervasive blue".

Comment: This problem appear when click the New menu at top left side

Comment: @Tschallacka maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776158/is-the-blue-area-greater-than-the-red-area helps ..?

Comment: [I'm trying](https://media1.giphy.com/media/BmmfETghGOPrW/giphy.gif) @Teemu but math is hard. Now i'm looking for a ruler to make measurements to I can calculate the area correctly

Comment: @tschallacka sorry I couldnt find the pen tool in paint :(. Better luck next time!

Comment: Next time use the snipping tool. It has a useful drawing feature.

Comment: @oh I did use the snipping tool but then copy/paste into mspaint for professional edits. Nothing but the best for Meta. At least now I've brushed up on the relevant memes.

Comment: This css fixes it: `.s-hero._fixed-width {
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    z-index: 0;
}`

Comment: @rene gah why are you so darned good at opening the comments thread?!

Comment: @coldspeed because I have no life.

Comment: @rene I feel awe and pity at the same time...